# ESP32 - Idf Arduino QueueHandle_t as function paramater

Tags: arduino, esp32, freertos

I am using ESP32 module and coding it using Arduino.
I am trying to read from Serial2 (attached to hc-05 bluetooth) and push it to FreeRTOS queue.
There is one task(task4F) pinned to core-1.
To achieve this I have created a class (MyBluetooth) and calling the read method of that class from the said xTask. If there is data in serial bus it should push it to queue.
It is able to read the data from serial but failed to push it to queue. I think, I am doing something wrong with the pointer but failed to identify that. I am attaching the code and error message with this, please suggest on this.

```
class MyBluetooth{

  QueueHandle_t queue; //QueueHandle_t queue;
  public:
  void begin(QueueHandle_t q){ //void begin(QueueHandle_t q){
    Serial2.begin(9600);
    queue = q;
  }  

  public:
  bool bluetoothRead() {
    if (Serial2.available()) {      
        String input = Serial2.readString();        
          const char* s = input.c_str();
          Serial.println("===========: "+String(s));
          xQueueSend(&queue, &s , 10); //xQueueSend(queue, &s , 10);
          Serial.println("+++++++++++: "+String(s));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  bool bluetoothWrite() {
    //TODO
    return false;
  }
};
MyBluetooth myBluetooth;

void task4F( void * pvParameters ) {
  while(true){ 
    if(myBluetooth.bluetoothRead()){
      Serial.println("=================");
    }
  }
}

QueueHandle_t qq;

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(112500);
  qq = xQueueCreate( 25, sizeof(char*) );
  if(qq == NULL){
    Serial.println("Error creating the queue");
  }
 myBluetooth.begin(&qq); //myBluetooth.begin(qq);
   xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
                    task4F,          // Task function. 
                    "Task",        // String with name of task. 
                    10000,            // Stack size in bytes. 
                    NULL,             // Parameter passed as input of the task 
                    1,                // Priority of the task. 
                    NULL,  // Task handle.
                    1);           

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Error Log:

```
20:26:22.418 -> ===========: input_string
20:26:22.418 -> abort() was called at PC 0x400832e5 on core 1
20:26:22.418 -> 
20:26:22.418 -> ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000
20:26:22.418 -> 
20:26:22.418 -> Backtrace: 0x40084e68:0x3ffb4220 0x400850dd:0x3ffb4240 0x400832e5:0x3ffb4260 0x40083411:0x3ffb4290 0x400d74ab:0x3ffb42b0 0x400d39c5:0x3ffb4570 0x400d3960:0x3ffb45c0 0x40086e12:0x3ffb45f0 0x40085af5:0x3ffb4620 0x400d0d0a:0x3ffb4660 0x400d0db6:0x3ffb46d0 0x400860ed:0x3ffb46f0
20:26:22.465 ->
```

**Note:**
Managed to fix it, mentioned it using comment. But have one question, as per my understating here we are following pass by value which will create a new object, is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
qq = xQueueCreate( 25, sizeof(char*) );
myBluetooth.begin(&qq);
```

`qq` is a `QueueHandle_t` which is a pointer/handle. You're then passing to your function the *address of* the *handle* rather than the handle itself. Remove the ampersand. Your compiler should actually be giving you an error about this... are you sure the code you posted is actually compiling as-is?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is working now, but can you please address one question, as per my understating here we are following pass by value which will create a new object, is it correct? I have edited the question please look it for more details

Comment: Yes, it's pass-by-value, but the value you're passing isn't a queue object, it's a _handle_ to one. Now you have a copy of the _handle_, not of the queue. Check out the parent site, https://stackoverflow.com/ for general programming topics - there you can find lots of existing Q&A on this.